# Plugin Options not saving options and doesn't work

Tags: plugin-development, options

So I've been making a plugin for wordpress that adds a custom post type for products, which
was fairly simple and i made that work.

Afterwards I wanted to make a settings page sub menu to the custom post type in the admin menu and then create some options.

So the first problem i encountered was that a warning showed up that said

```
Warning:  Illegal string offset 'option1' in C:/blablablal on line 96
```

And from what I understand that means that the option doesn't know that it's supposed to save the options in an array but tries to put it in a string instead. So I found a way to make the warning go away by adding brackets to the variable.

```
$kns_options[] = get_option('kns_products_options');
```

(I don't know if this is a solution or not, but I couldn't find anything about it on loads of google searches)

So after the warning went away, I started to try and add options via the form I've created, but the options just don't want to save. I've tried to var_dump the variable, but it comes out empty.. Is there a typo somewhere, because i sure as hell can't find it!

I'll post the code below, please tell me if i should repost it in pastebin or something!

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'kns_register_products_post_type' );

function kns_register_products_post_type() {
    // Registrerar en custom post type som heter produkter
    register_post_type('produkter',
    array(
        'labels' => 
            array(
                'name' => 'Produkter',
                'singular_name' => 'Produkt',
                'add_new' => 'Lägg till ny',
                'add_new_item' => 'Lägg till ny Produkt',
                'edit_item' => 'Ändra Produkt',
                'new_item' => 'Ny Produkt',
                'view_item' => 'Visa Produkt',
                'search_items' => 'Sök Produkter',
                'not_found' => 'Inga produkter hittades',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'Inga produkter hittades i papperskorgen',
                'parent_item_colon' => 'Produkt Förälder:',
                'menu_name' => 'Produkter'
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => array('category'),
        'menu_position' => 20,
        )
    );

}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'kns_products_create_settings_submenu' );

function kns_products_create_settings_submenu() {
    // Skapar sub menu för Produkter-fliken
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=produkter', 'Inställningar', 'Inställningar', 'manage_options', 'product_settings', 'kns_products_settings_page' );
    // Kallar på register_setting funktionen
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'kns_products_register_settings');
}

function kns_products_register_settings() {
    register_setting( 'kns_products_settings_group', 'kns_products_options', 'kns_sanitize_options');
}

function kns_sanitize_options( $input ) {
    $input['option1'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['option1'] );
    $input['option2'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['option2'] );
}

function kns_products_settings_page() {
?>  
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Produktinställningar</h2>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php 
    settings_fields( 'kns_products_settings_group' );
    $kns_options[] = get_option('kns_products_options'); 
    var_dump($kns_options);
    ?>
    <table class="form-table">
    <h3>Utseende</h3>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row"><label for="option1">Blajja</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="option1" name="kns_options[option1]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $kns_options['option1'] ); ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row"><label for="option2">Annan Blajja</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="option2" name="kns_options[option2]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $kns_options['option2'] ); ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Spara inställningar" />
    </p>

</form> 
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I really need help, I've been at this for hours now..

EDIT:

var_dump results are

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: you have a typo in your form: `kns_option[option1]`, the letter `s` is missing in `kns_option`.

Comment: No, don't post to pastebin. Code should be posted here but it would help to identify the line that that error references.

Comment: @Milo Thanks, i corrected it but the options still wont save..

Comment: @s_ha_dum When i remove the brackets and the error shows again, it points to both the rows where the input text fields are.

Comment: Are the options not _saving_ or not _printing_. There is a difference. Look in the database and check.

Comment: @s_ha_dum The kns_products_options is found in wp_options, but it has no entries in it. Therefore not saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning data from the sanitize function:

```
function kns_sanitize_options( $input ) {
    $input['option1'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['option1'] );
    $input['option2'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['option2'] );
}
```

There is therefore nothing to save. Try:

```
function kns_sanitize_options( $input ) {
    $input['option1'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['option1'] );
    $input['option2'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['option2'] );
    return $input;
}
```

Secondly, you've registered the name of your options as `kns_products_options`

```
register_setting( 'kns_products_settings_group', 'kns_products_options', 'kns_sanitize_options');
```

But you are using `kns_options` in the form.

```
<input type="text" id="option1" name="kns_options[option1]" //...
```

The API doesn't know how to find the data so `$input` in your sanitization callback is always `null`. Make that name attribute match the name you registered.

```
<input type="text" id="option1" name="kns_products_options[option1]" //...
```

Comment: Okay, so now it seems to add an array to the database instead of being empty, however it doesn't print any values in the input fields.

Comment: Don't use the square brackets when you retrieve the data.

Comment: In the input field value or when defining the kns_options variable?

I removed the brackets from where i defined the kns_options variable and the error didnt show, but still no print in the input text fields

Comment: So I just saw that the arrays actually are empty. So it manages to create the options at least but the options wont save the strings.

Comment: Seems like you have a few bugs. I am going to need to install this and test it but I don't have the time right now. If you don't get an answer remind me later by putting @s_ha_dum in a comment.

Comment: Okay! http://pastebin.com/1Q6emUvB contains the full plugin! Thank you for putting effort into this, I appreciate it!

Comment: bumping this question!

Comment: @JakeSnake  : See the edit.

Comment: Thank you, i thought that the name attribute was supposed to match the variable..